# org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException for <mvc:resources../>

Tags: javascript, css, hibernate, spring-mvc, tiles2

Well I have website template which coordinates with some css and js files.

Now I have created Spring , Hibernate and Tiles example. It works fine. but now m integrating with my template. so that I created resources folder inside webapp folder. and put all CSS and Js files in respective folders.

xxx-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/mytheme/" cache-period="1000" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/config/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.rohitmore.xxx</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

```
But getting Exception on this line  

<mvc:resources ... /> 

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 94; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.
```

I am looking for you earliest convenience.

Comment: Do you have the `spring-webmvc` library on the classpath?

Comment: Yes I have already included spring-webmvc.

Comment: What version of the lib? Try cleaning and recompiling.

Comment: Spring Version 3.0.1. 
Yeah, I disable build automatically option and performed manually. but still exception is there.